# How do I duplicate the functionality of ugui's onClick (button component) in inspector (Unity)?

Tags: unity, gui

I'm trying to create the same functionality that occurs when you are working with a button in uGui in Unity. I know that I have to create a custom inspector, but i'm not sure where to go from there.

Essentially the functionality allows you to drag and drop a script to it's on click portion in the inspector, and then it gives you a list of functions for that script to select. This may sound a little confusing, so here are a few pictures demonstrating the functionality i'm trying to replicate.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

As you can see above the functionality allows you to drag in a script, select a function to link, and do this for as many or as little scripts as you want by pressing the + or - buttons on the bottom right.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [UnityEvents](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent.html) to make use of such functionality. Derive  a class from  UnityEvent and then then declare a public member:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class MyEvent : UnityEvent<int> {}

public MyEvent onClick;
```

This will show up as the custom inspector widget you want. To send the event you do something like this:

```
onClick.Invoke(1);
```

Take look at this [tutorial](http://zebugames.com/blog/make-a-slick-rating-prompt-in-unity-tutorial-part-1/) I made on a Rating Bar widget that uses Unity Events